# Exclude custom content type from search ( tried everything )

Tags: search

so I am here after googling the hell out of this problem.

My issue is the following, I am trying to exlucde a content type from showing up in resulsts.

I am using an autocomplete module called : **Search Autocomplete** , this module does the search..

So after researching the topic, to exclude content type from searches, I instaleld **Search Configuration Module**

I configured this module to exclude everyone but the admin from doing any type of search, but whatever I do seems to have no effect...
I am out of ideas and currently dont know what to do..

I also tried the lightweight search restrict plugin, but that doesnt seem to have any effect aswell.

This is the code I have inside the template.php

```
function MYSITE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
    $form['search_block_form']['#title'] = t(''); // Change the text on the label element
    $form['search_block_form']['#title_display'] = 'invisible'; // Toggle label visibility
    $form['search_block_form']['#default_value'] = t(''); // Set a default value for the textfield
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Cautare'); // Change the text on the submit button
    $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['alt'] = "Search Button"; //add alt tag
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t( 'Enter search terms...' );


// Add extra attributes to the text box
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Cautare..';}";
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['onblur'] = "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Cautare..';}";
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['onfocus'] = "if (this.value == 'Search Site') {this.value = '';}";
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That module is for core search only, it doesn't apply to the apachesolr module. People tend to use Search API these days, but IIRC the apachesolr module has the functionality you want built into its admin pages out of the box

Comment: @Clive I spoke about 2 modules, which one are you talking about?

I looked if I have the apachesolr module installed and I dont , can you be more clear please :D

Comment: Why would you include apachesolr code in your question if you’re not using the module? That’s just confusing!

Comment: you are completly right, i forgot to erase that line, ill edit the post and do it now ..
EDIT** done I erased that line.
What are my choices here? I am new to drupal and everything its kinda confusing as to why its not  working

Answer (score 0):

Ok so all this confusion was pretty easy to solve from inside teh views module, I had to exclude in the views module the content type and that was it no need for uneccesary modules to exclude content types from search